# How to fix '.create is not a function' error in mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I am trying to initialize a seed.js file to have something to start in my database but when I run `node bin/seed.js` I keep getting `'TypeError: Celebrity.create is not a function'`

I have tried reinstalling `mongoose` npm package, I have been looking for similar problems and after some time looking it seems to me that everything is OK and I can't find the problem

Here is my relevant `app.js` code

```
mongoose
    .connect('mongodb://localhost/cinema', { useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(x => {
        console.log(`Connected to Mongo! Database name: "${x.connections[0].name}"`)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('Error connecting to mongo', err)
    })
```

here is my celebrity.model.js

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const celebritySchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: String,
        occupation: String,
        catchPhrase: String
    },
    { timestamps: true }
)

const Celebrity = mongoose.model('Celebrity', celebritySchema)

module.exports = Celebrity
```

here is my seed.js

```
const Celebrity = '../models/celebrity.model.js'

const dbName = 'cinema'
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost/${dbName}`, { useNewUrlParser: true })

const celebrities = [
    {
        name: 'Alex',
        occupation: 'Parado',
        catchPhrase: 'Teo ayudameeee'
    }
]

Celebrity.create(celebrities, err => {
    if (err) {
        throw err
    }
    console.log(`Created ${celebrities.length} celebrities`)
    mongoose.connection.close()
})
```

and this is the error

```
Celebrity.create(celebrities, err => {
          ^

TypeError: Celebrity.create is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/nacho/Ironhack/week4/day5/de/lab-mongoose-movies/starter-code/bin/seed.js:31:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:21:11
```

I expected the seed to create 1 value in my data base but i get the error

Comment: I had a similar issue, I was writing ```.Create``` but it should be ```.create```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to require the model file in your seed file like this:

```
const Celebrity = require('../models/celebrity.model.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. The solution was in the correct import. I have in models/contact.js :
module.exports = {
Contact,
schemas,
};

And in controllers/contacts.js I changed
const Contact = require("../models/contact.js");
into
const { Contact } = require("../models/contact.js");

Comment: This solution does not apply to the code in question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).